# Debug Assertion [Vector]

Tags: c++, vector

I'm wondering if something is wrong with my code especially the vector implementation?

Well,I was just exposed to the use of vector yesterday by people here.

In my college,I only learnt array.So,the usage of vector is kinda new to me.

To my understanding,vector is basically a dynamic array.-Correct me if I were wrong

Well,so lets go with my code.I got the following error: "Vector subscript out of range" after inputting n value.

**EDIT:Fixed my earlier issue.Thanks to @quantdev .Now I noticed that my values aren't sorted.**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

//Function prototype
void Insertion_sort(vector<int> AR, int n);
void random_store(int val, vector<int> &aVec);


int main()
{
    int nvalue;
    vector<int> int_vector;
    cout << "How many numbers would you like to generate?\n";
    cin >> nvalue;//get input from user

    random_store(nvalue, int_vector);//pass user input into random() function

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
void random_store(int val, vector<int> &aVec)//store randomly generated value
{
    int num;//represent random integer output
    for (int i = 0; i < val; i++)
    {
        aVec.push_back(rand() % val + 1);//push each generated value into vector
    }
    Insertion_sort(aVec,val);//Pass the vector into a function to perform sorting
    cout << " \n The sorted array is as follows \n ";
    for (int i = 1; i <= val; i++)//Print sorted array
    {
        cout << " \n Element " << i << " : " << aVec[i] << endl;//will loop from aVec 1st array till n value
    }
}

void Insertion_sort(vector<int> AR, int n)//insertion sort function
{
    int j, val;//iterate through entire list
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
            val = AR[i];
            j = i - 1;
        while (j >= 0 && AR[j] > val){
                AR[j + 1] = AR[j];
                j = j - 1;
        }
            AR[j + 1] = val;
    }
} // end of insertion sort function
```

Comment: Please don't edit your question to have the code fixed, it makes it confusing for anyone seeing the question at the first time. Instead, leave the question as it was and accept the answer. If you have a new question  , post a new question or edit your question to ask the new question (as well as the old question)

Comment: Re. the values not being sorted, `Insertion_sort` takes a vector by value, so it sorts a local copy (the copy of the vector in the calling function remains untouched). Perhaps you meant to take a vector by reference, `vector<int> &AR`

Comment: Ok.noted guys. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your vector contains `val` values, so indexes are in `[0, val-1]`, but within this loop :

```
for (int i = 1; i <= val; i++)
```

The last iteration will try to access the element at index `val+1`, which is out of bounds (it also misses the first element, at index 0)

Change it to :

```
for (int i = 0; i < val; i++)
```

And since indexes are of type `std::size_t` :

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < val; i++)
```

**Note:**

Your sort function takes a vector by value, sorting a **copy** of the vector. You probably want to pass by reference instead :

```
void Insertion_sort(vector<int>& AR, int n)
```

Comment: Ok,it fixed my issue..but do you have any idea why my output isnt a sorted values?

Comment: @MINGKEATLIM see my note, you need to pass a reference of your vector

Comment: Sorry,just noticed your note.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping out.Have a nice Sunday @quantdev

Comment: The last iteration will access the element at index `val` which is out of bounds